# dpkg on iPhone: edit a property list with a postinst script

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, dpkg

I need to change a single boolean value in a property list upon installation of a package (it is dependent on a system setting that is not configurable through a GUI). How can I edit a property list with a command in a post-install script in dpkg on iPhone?